# access sequence in another schema using a synonym

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to access a sequence that is:

A.  Located in another schema
B.  Is actually a synonym to another database through a dblink.

What works:

```
select schema.sequence@dblink.nextval from dual;
```

What doesn't work:

```
select schema.synonym.sequence.nextval from dual;
```

The above returns a '%s: invalid identifier'

Is it possible to access the remote sequence without using the `dblink` annotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use synonym for remote sequence object.

**Database 1**

```
SQL> conn jay

SQL> create sequence myseq increment by 1;

Sequence created.
```

**Database 2**

```
SQL> conn jay

SQL> create database link dbl_db1 connect to jay identified by jay using 'DB1';

Database link created.

SQL> create synonym myseq_syno for jay.myseq@dbl_db1;

Synonym created.

SQL> select myseq_syno.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
     1
```

Comment: thank you...i was creating a synonym to a table instead of the sequence directly